# how to get wordpress posts description and caption?

Tags: php, json, api, wordpress

Iam trying to get 5 featured post from wordpress, to achieve this target i have offset 5 recent post .I successfully fetched post id , images . But i failed to get every  posts description .i tried the code below but it only give me only 1 post description not all 5 .

```
$my_posts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => 5,
'offset'      => 5,
'orderby'     => 'post_date',
'order'       => 'DESC',
'post_type'   => 'post',
'post_status' => 'publish'));


  foreach($my_posts as $post) {

$data[] = 

    array(
       "id" => $post->ID,
      "title" => $post->post_title,
      "image" => get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID),
     // "content" =>$post['post_excerpt'] 
      "content" => apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content)
    );
                       }
```

Answer (score 3):

You get the description `the_content()` function within the loop. More information about this function is on [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) page

For caption, you could use `the_excerpt()` function with the loop